# Python - Movendo arquivos para outra pasta

Tags: python-3.x

Alguém poderia dar-me um help no código abaixo?

**Objetivo: mover arquivos de uma pasta para outra.**

Tenho na área de trabalho duas pastas, uma chamada "teste" e a outra "teste2".

Na primeira, tenho 7 arquivos textos de extensão ".txt".

Estão nomeados da seguinte forma: "teste (1).txt", "teste (2).txt", etc.

**O problema que está ocorrendo:**

Ao executar o loop while, o sistema move uma porção dos arquivos, depois tenho que executar novamente, ai ele move outra porção e depois, ele move o ultimo arquivo, concluindo o processo com todos os arquivos na pasta "teste2".

```
import shutil
import os

oldAdress = 'C:/Users/WJRS/Desktop/teste/' #pasta origem
newAdress = 'C:/Users/WJRS/Desktop/teste2/' #pasta destino

lista = os.listdir(oldAdress) #lista separando apenas os arquivos do caminho.

x = 0
#A função len() retorna o valor de 7, pois são 7 arquivos.
#No entanto, como se trata de uma lista, o indice a ser percorrido é de 0 a 6.
#por isso, 'x' começa em zero.
while x <= (len(os.listdir(oldAdress))-1):
    caminhoCompleto_old = oldAdress + lista[x] #variável recebe caminho + arquivo, conforme indice
    caminhoCompleto_new = newAdress + lista[x] #variável recebe caminho + arquivo, conforme indice
    shutil.move(caminhoCompleto_old, caminhoCompleto_new) #módulo 'shutil.move()' move os arquivos
    print(x, '-', lista[x]) #apenas para ver como está sendo feito
    x += 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse problema ocorre devido a chamada `os.listdir()` no teste de condição do *while*:

`while x <= (len(os.listdir(oldAdress))-1):`

A cada iteração do looping, o comprimento da lista de arquivos é recalculado e fica **menor**, conforme cada arquivo é movido, portanto o looping termina antes de transferir todos os arquivos.

A solução é calcular o tamanho da lista fora do looping *while* e armazenar esse valor em uma variável (que será utilizada na comparação do looping).

Segue abaixo o código corrigido:

```
import shutil
import os

oldAdress = 'C:/Users/WJRS/Desktop/teste/' #pasta origem
newAdress = 'C:/Users/WJRS/Desktop/teste2/' #pasta destino

lista = os.listdir(oldAdress) #lista separando apenas os arquivos do caminho.

# *** lista_len recebe o tamanho da lista ***
lista_len = len(lista)
x = 0

# *** Utilizar a variável ao invés de chamar 'os.listdir()' ***
while x < lista_len:
    caminhoCompleto_old = oldAdress + lista[x] #variável recebe caminho + arquivo, conforme indice
    caminhoCompleto_new = newAdress + lista[x] #variável recebe caminho + arquivo, conforme indice
    shutil.move(caminhoCompleto_old, caminhoCompleto_new) #módulo 'shutil.move()' move os arquivos
    print(x, '-', lista[x]) #apenas para ver como está sendo feito
    x += 1
```

Comment: Gomiero, agradeço sua ajuda! Funcionou perfeitamente!

Answer (score 0):

```
__author__ = '@britodfbr'

import shutil
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join, basename


def move(path_origem, path_destino, ext='zip'):
    for item in [join(path_origem, f) for f in listdir(path_origem) if isfile(join(path_origem, f)) and f.endswith(ext)]:
        #print(item)
        shutil.move(item, join(path_destino, basename(item)))
        print('moved "{}" -> "{}"'.format(item, join(path_destino, basename(item))))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    move('/tmp/a', '/tmp/b')
```

Saída:

```
moved "/tmp/a/file7.zip" -> "/tmp/b/file7.zip"
moved "/tmp/a/file4.zip" -> "/tmp/b/file4.zip"
moved "/tmp/a/file0.zip" -> "/tmp/b/file0.zip"
moved "/tmp/a/file3.zip" -> "/tmp/b/file3.zip"
moved "/tmp/a/file1.zip" -> "/tmp/b/file1.zip"
moved "/tmp/a/file6.zip" -> "/tmp/b/file6.zip"
moved "/tmp/a/file9.zip" -> "/tmp/b/file9.zip"
moved "/tmp/a/file2.zip" -> "/tmp/b/file2.zip"
moved "/tmp/a/file5.zip" -> "/tmp/b/file5.zip"
moved "/tmp/a/file10.zip" -> "/tmp/b/file10.zip"
moved "/tmp/a/file8.zip" -> "/tmp/b/file8.zip"
moved "/tmp/a/file01.zip" -> "/tmp/b/file01.zip"
```

Relacionada com este link: pt.stackoverflow.com/a/308147/62736

Comment: Isto não fornece uma resposta à pergunta. Para criticar ou solicitar esclarecimento de um autor, deixe um comentário abaixo da publicação dele. - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/173177)

Comment: corrigido! valeu.